# PHP - Issue with removing or modifying specific item in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, array-push

I have a multidimensional array. The parent array includes items that each item inside is an array with its properties.

insertProduct.php checks everytime I add a new product to the array if the product already exists. If it doesn't it pushes it to the array, if it already exists it finds it and adds +1 to its quantity.

I am trying to create a functionality where pressing a button "Undo" removes the latest addition whether it was a whole product (which means its QTY would be 1 so it removes it altoghether) or if the latest addition was just a QTY increase (from 1 to 2) then remove 1 from the QTY.

However my issue is when I add a product that already exists but is not in the last spot of the array, the QTY does increase as it should be but then the UNDO does not do -1 to this item's QTY.

I don't know if it's alright to post a video but [here's the pattern of the problem in a short gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZCfo.jpg)

insertProduct.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['myArray'])) {
    $inserted_products = $_SESSION['myArray'];
    $position = array_search($inserted_product_ean, array_column($inserted_products,0)); 

    //check if new product already exists
    if ($position !== false) {                                      
        $inserted_products[$position][2] = $inserted_products[$position][2] + 1;
        $latest_product = $inserted_products[$position];
        $_SESSION['latestProduct'] = $latest_product;
        $_SESSION['myArray'] = $inserted_products;

    } else {
        array_push($inserted_products, $product); //$product is an array of info about the item inserted
        $latest_product = $product;
        $_SESSION['latestProduct'] = $latest_product;
        $_SESSION['myArray'] = $inserted_products;
    }

} else {
    $latest_product = $product;
    $_SESSION['latestProduct'] = $latest_product;
    array_push($inserted_products, $product);
    $_SESSION['myArray'] = $inserted_products;
}
```

deleteLastEntry.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['myArray'])) {
    $inserted_products = $_SESSION['myArray'];
    $inserted_products_length = count($inserted_products);
    if ($inserted_products_length > 0){
        $latest_product = $_SESSION['latestProduct'];
        $qty = $latest_product[2];
        if ($qty !== false && $qty > 1) {
            $qty = $qty - 1;        
            $latest_product[2] = $qty;
            array_pop($inserted_products);
            array_push($inserted_products, $latest_product);
            $_SESSION['myArray'] = $inserted_products;
        }else{
            array_pop($inserted_products);
            $_SESSION['myArray'] = $inserted_products;
        }
    }else{
        echo '<div class="error-msg">No products to remove</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: you planning is wrong just add or remove to the array key of the relevant product. try to setup another key of last added so you will have shopping list key which will be array of items and on the same level you will have latest added.  it will save the logic and should be easy.

Comment: @talsibony Thanks for your reply, can you be more specific ?

Comment: Well, if you know what `array_pop` does, then your problem is obvious. It always takes the first element in the array. Why didn't you find out the position like you do in insert? That way you could directly modify the quantity or unset the element, without resorting to popping/pushing.